# Calling startactivityforresult inside activity that has been called by startactivityforresult

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I have this issue that I have a list of `A` and I can add new `A`, so I `startactivityforresult` activity with form for `A` and there is also a button for selecting `AType`, so I `startactivityforresult` another activity with `AType` list.
Problem comes when I do post back result in `AType` list.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("aType", aType);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

And the result is pushed back to `A` List instead of `A` Form.
Is this normal behavior or I am doing something wrong?
If this is normal behavior, what can I do to push back result to `A` Form instead of `A` List.

If you need more code - I will provide, but I find it now irrelevant.

---

I have found out that `A` Form finishes after `startactivityforresult` call. But why?

Comment: Can you please provide a **complete** code example? Show all activity classes involved here and just the parts of their code which is related to your question. For tips on creating a good code example, see [mcve].

Comment: Posted answer below. I had `noHistory="true"` for this Activity :/

Answer (score 0):

**Activity1:**

```
Intent intent-=new Intent(this,myclass.class);
startActivityforResult(intent,100);
```

Override the method OnACtivity result in Activity 1

**Activity2:**

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Comment: Did you understand the question?

Comment: @Anonymous, I believe not, do you know if this is normal?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I have `noHistory="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` for activity `A Form`, that is why it was going back to `A List` Activity